# Pytorch training loss function throws: "TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable"

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I use Python 3.x, and pytorch 1.5.0 with a GPU. I am trying to write a simple multinomial logistic regression using mnist data.

My issue is the loss() function throws a `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable` while looping through the training batches. The thing that baffles me is that **the error does not show up in the first iteration of the loop, but for the second batch, I get the full error below:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/207/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1448, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/207/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/pytorch_tutorial/Pytorch_feed_fwd_310720.py", line 78, in <module>
    loss = loss(preds,ys)
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

The loss() function here is simply `loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. The full code is below. Any pointers would be very welcome.

```
    for epoch in range(5):

        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            xs, ys = data
            opt.zero_grad()
            preds = net(xs)
            loss = loss(preds,ys)
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 1000 == 999:  # print every 1000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0

        print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))

    a=1
```

Comment: before the ```loss = loss(preds, ys)```, try ```print(type(loss))```.  I'm guessing you're overwriting what loss is.

Comment: trust me. you aren't the only one.  Been there, done that.  :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you are setting `loss` locally in the loop.

change `loss = loss(preds, ys)` to `_loss = loss(preds, ys)`